# How do I change date format to YYYY-MM in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I change date format to YYYY-MM in SQL? I could only find ways that reorder yyyy mm and dd, and one way to make it "Jan 2022", but I need "2022-01" without day.

```
CONCAT(YEAR(mydate), '-', MONTH(mydate))
```

Doesn't work with an error "function year(date) does not exist"

```
DATE_FORMAT(mydate, "%Y-%m")
```

Doesn't work with an error "column "%Y-%m" does not exist".

DB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE campaign(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  platform TEXT,
  label TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE context_stat(  
  campaign_id INT,
  mydate DATE,  
  impressions INT,
  clicks INT,
  cost NUMERIC(8,2),
  FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES campaign (id),
  UNIQUE(campaign_id, date)
);

CREATE TABLE google_analytics( 
  campaign_id INT, 
  mydate DATE,  
  sessions INT,
  bounces INT,
  pageviews INT,
  transactions INT,
  revenue INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id) REFERENCES campaign (id),
  UNIQUE(campaign_id, date)
);
```

Comment: Use mysql function `SUBSTRING` on the date column?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this, if your date is a date (or dateTime) column :

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(myDate), '-', MONTH(myDate)) ;
```

Or

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(myDate, "%Y-%m");
```

Comment: Does this work in PostgreSQL? I copyed your answer and get either "function year(date) does not exist" or "column "%Y-%m" does not exist".
May be it has something to do with the fact that my date column is called "date"?
If so, how can I work around it, assuming I cannot rename columns (readonly).

Comment: Edited: Doesn`t work even with name "mydate".

Comment: SQL syntax is for MySQL. Mydate is an an example, replace mydate by your fields name.

Comment: With Postgres you can use : 
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('05 Dec 2000', 'YYYY-MM')